# Connect Four Horizontal winner

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a connect four game and I'm having some trouble with the horizontal loop. The loop below works and it's for a vertical win. I have a two labels for each row and two labels for each column one for the color blue and one for the color red. When I add in my other labels I cant seem to find where I take the step-1 in order to change labels and go upwards with the next label. I have also tried adding a whole new loop below that just dedicated to the horizontal winnings.

```
    For i = 5 To 0 Step -1`
        If board(i, 0) = 0 Then
            board(i, 0) = pturn
            If pturn = 1 Then
                Labelboard(i, 0).BackColor = Color.Red
                CounterB = 0
                lblcounterBlue.Text = "Matches = " & CounterB

                CounterR = CounterR + 1
                lblCounterRed.Text = "Matches = " & CounterR


            ElseIf pturn = 2 Then
                Labelboard(i, 0).BackColor = Color.Blue
                CounterR = 0
                lblCounterRed.Text = "Matches = " & CounterR

                CounterB = CounterB + 1
                lblcounterBlue.Text = "Matches = " & CounterB

            End If

            pturn = pturn + 1

            If pturn = 3 Then pturn = 1
            If CounterR = 4 Then
                MsgBox("Game Over")
            End If
            If CounterB = 4 Then
                MsgBox("Game Over")
            End If

            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Do you understand _why_ the existing code works?  A horizontal loop could work the same way just looping on the columns/rows in the opposite order.

Comment: @DStanley I understand how the existing code works. However the horizontal loop I don't understand because each time I click the button it should move upwards to the next label.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your setup, but hopefully this will get you close enough for you to get things working. I'm having to make a few assumptions, but I've tried to declare a constant each time I have to make the code more readable and easier for you to adapt to what you've already written.

What I've written is a function that lets you know if a specific space is part of winning streak. It assumes board() is public. If pturn is also public, you could make this even more efficient as long as you call it every turn, as noted in the comments. If you know which space was the last one played, you can maximize efficiency by only calling the function for that space (assuming you call it at the end of every player turn). If you don't know which space was played last, you can loop through every space in board() and test each one.

```
Function winner(rowNum As Integer, colNum As Integer) As Integer
'Returns 0 if space does not create a win, or the winning player number if it does
'Change to winner(...) As Boolean <--To only test current player

    Dim minRow As Integer = LBound(board, 0)
    Dim maxRow As Integer = UBound(board, 0)
    Dim minColumn As Integer = LBound(board, 1)
    Dim maxColumn As Integer = UBound(board, 1)

    'These are the values I assume are in board()
    '(I don't actually use them in the code)
    Const emptySpace As Integer = 0
    Const red As Integer = 1
    Const blue As Integer = 2

    Dim player As Integer
    Dim streak As Integer
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer 'loop placeholders
    Dim v As Integer, h As Integer 'control search direction

    For v = 0 To 1
        For h = -1 To 1
            If v = 1 Or h = 1 Then
            'These loops and test check each direction (vertical, horizontal and
            'both diagonals) for a win exactly once.

                player = board(rowNum, colNum)
                If player > 0 Then 'If player = pturn  <-- to only check current player
                    streak = 1

                    'check positive direction
                    r = rowNum + h
                    c = colNum + v
                    Do While r >= minRow And r <= maxRow And c >= minColumn And c <= maxColumn
                        If board(r, c) = player Then
                            streak = streak + 1
                            If streak = 4 Then
                                Return player 'True <--If testing only current player
                            Else
                                r = r + h
                                c = c + v
                            End If
                        Else
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    Loop

                    'check negative direction
                    r = rowNum - h
                    c = colNum - v
                    Do While r >= minRow And r <= maxRow And c >= minColumn And c <= maxColumn
                        If board(r, c) = player Then
                            streak = streak + 1
                            If streak = 4 Then
                                Return player 'True <--If testing only current player
                            Else
                                r = r - h
                                c = c - v
                            End If
                        Else
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    Loop
                End If
            End If
        Next h
    Next v

    Return 0 'Function has completed and no winner was found
    'Return False <-- If only testing current player
End Function
```

Comment: I forgot that you didn't actually ask for diagonal wins. If you don't want to allow them, change `If v = 1 Or h = 1 Then` to `If v + h = 1 Then`